# How to trigger email if a file is not found in job monitoring using shell scripting?

Tags: linux, shell, unix

I have a task in job monitoring using shell scripting. I have to trigger an alert email if file is not found in my shared path where the job takes the source files. As I am finding difficulty, can anyone help me?

Comment: Your problem description lacks details. Please [edit] your question, add the code you currently have and ask a specific question about what you are having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this approach?

```
if ! test -f /path/To/YourFile
then
    mail -s "Source file not found" user@example.com < body_email.txt
fi
```